# How to align the contents inside a ListboxSelect of Tk GUI

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

[image: Content alignment show different between console & GUI]

Refer to above picture. I adding the content into a ListboxSelect of Tk GUI by following format code, seems in the output of command line, everything works and align correctly. but when the content shown in the GUI, always not align as I wanted.

Any suggestion on this issue?

```
$lb_ccrdetail->insert(
                    'end',
                    sprintf( "%s%s%-50s%s",
                        $ccidstring,
                        ' 'x (15-length($ccidstring)),
                        $prodstring,
                        #' 'x (20-length($prodstring)),
                        $detailstring
                    )
                );
```

Comment: I know Tk::ListBox but not ListBoxSelect. Try trimming $prodstring before sprintf.

Comment: The terminal window looks like columns because it's using a fixed width font.  You can either use a fixed width font yourself, or, if you really want a proportional font, you'll need to break out the columns into separate widgets.

Comment: Thanks for help. I fixed the issue by using a mono font.
`code`$mono_font = $WinMain->fontCreate('mono', -family => 'Courier', -size => 8);